# Angular 7 Show/hide tables based on object keys & set div based on object values

Tags: html, binding, angular7

I have one object

> {"HH": "HouseHold", "A1834": "Adult 18-34", "B1214": "Boy 12-14"}

from which i have to show object values in div at 1 time

```
<button>Previous</button>
<div>HouseHold</div> <!-- Showed 1st value on page load -->
<button>Next</button>
```

& based on this objects i have generated 3 tables with their id as object keys

```
<table #HH >....</table>
<table #A1834 >....</table>
<table #B1214 >....</table>
```

**Task:**

When page loads div is set to `<div>HouseHold</div>` & only 1st table with id **HH** is visible and other tables are hide/display:none

For eg:

```
<table #HH style="display:block;" >....</table>
<table #A1834 style="display:none;">....</table>
<table #B1214 style="display:none;">....</table>
```

whenever user clicks on **Next** button the div value changes to `<div>Adult 18-34</div>` and table with id **A1834** is visible/display:block & other 2 tables should be hide/display:none

For eg:

```
<table #HH style="display:none;" >....</table>
<table #A1834 style="display:block;">....</table>
<table #B1214 style="display:none;">....</table>
```

similarly on Next click div value changes to `<div>Boy 12-14</div>` and table with id B1214 is visible/display:block & other 2 tables hide/display:none

& vice-versa for Previous button.

How can i do this in angular 7 by binding object to div & tables?
Angular newbie here.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use `*ngIf` concept which is specially provided by Angular.First of all you write all table in Html Component and then in every tables div write like this

```
<div *ngIf="HouseHold">your household table contains</div>
```

So like this use with ngIf you can easily load the one table at a time.
 For more details ,please check this [Angular ngIF](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)